Would it be moral for Danish resitance in WW2 to kill collaborators?
Denmark in World War 2 surrendered in a day. It remained occupied well until the end of the war in May 1945. It surrendered because its armed forces could not realistically resist the Wehrmacht. During the war there was a Danish resistance who among other things helped some thousands of Danish Jews escape to Sweden.
Was it moral for Danish resistance to murder collaborators considering that it would, IMO, not have any impact or have a negative impact on the Danish peoples, and negligible impact on the war?

This really isn't the right site to ask for discussion of opinion-related topics because both discussion and opinion-based questions are discouraged. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about this topic to direct you to a better site.

"collaborator" is too broad. One might see everyone a collaborator who does not actively resist or sabotage the Germans. Others would deem someone to be a collaborator only if he actively betrays dissenters to the Gestapo.

@vsz The word "collaborator" derives from Latin "collaborare", to labour together. If a fellow engineer works with me on a project, we collaborate; someone who merely fails to sabotage my project is not a collaborator. If there is a military occupation, "collaborator" generally implies that the person has actively supported the invaders.

IMHO "murder" is emotive in this context: many people don't use the word "murder" when a soldier kills an enemy in battle, or the victim of aggression kills in self defence. Courts often have to decide whether a killing was murder, manslaughter, or justified homicide.

@SimonCrase Murder is “the premeditated, unlawful taking of a life".  Was there a law passed by the Danish gov't in exile that legalized killing compatriot collaborators? This is just semantics btw.

@SimonCrase actively supported, in what exactly? Worked in a bakery and sold them bread? Delivered them supplies? Or ratted out resistance members? Even in "collaboration" there are many levels.

@vsz I wonder whether you realize that there was a war going on? The Resistance (was there just one in Denmark? There were multiple groups in France) had to decide which collaborators to target. There was a risk involved in each action, so that would be balanced against the value (to the enemy) of each target. Sadly they had to make these decisions without your valuable input.

@max When a country is invaded, its laws are in abeyance: there is no way that the original laws can be enforced without the blessing of the enemy. It is meaningless to talk about whether any action against the enemy is lawful.

@max you said 'Murder is “the premeditated, unlawful taking of a life"'.  That is totally wrong in every way; it's just your definition of an incredibly controversial word.  And indeed each step of your sentence (eg "unlawful") is totally meaningless; by which I mean "you are simply stating what your beliefs are".  In your comment "this is just semantics" you are describing your own exposition.

i have no idea how you are supposed to show that anything is moral or immoral, ethics is sophistry and hand waving

Denmark in World War 2 surrendered in a day because it was small compared to Germany and it had no tank battalions, no air force to speak of, and an insignificant navy with no submarines. Military resistance against the Wehrmacht was hence completely futile.
The fact that the Danish resistance could kill collaborators without Nazi reprisals was an informal arrangement between the Danes and the Germans.
Had the resistance instead targeted German occupation officials instead of Danish citizens, there would have been severe reprisals involving the random killing of Danish civilians.
The Danes were "allowed" to do this because the Nazi occupation officials considered the Danes to be the "little brothers" of the Germanic master race, and therefore cut them slack which was not given to the governments of other occupied countries.
The Danish movie "Citron og Flammen" is a dramatization of that peculiar wartime equilibrium.

tnx the titbit of info

I like this answer, although it doesn't address the issues of "ethics" or "morality" raised by the question. It may be that the facts are the best answer, and one must form his own opinions.

How does this answer the question in the title? Also, this could really use a supporting reference. It is far from logical. While I have no deep knowledge of the Danish experience, German occupation would not imply no policing. Killing occupiers would obviously trigger reprisals, whereas killing collaborators might be a local police matter. It does not imply a clean slate to a resistance. It seems more obvious that Germans would not invest significant resources into policing given they were fighting a war elsewhere.

wartime behavior is under to obligation to be logical. See the movie. My parents came from Denmark. Second-guessing nazi behavior from 80 years ago is a fruitless enterprise.

There was no official or even informal "arrangement" between the Danish resistance and German authorities allowing the targeting of collaborators without reprisals. Reprisals did occur: The Germans did carry out reprisals against resistance activities in Denmark, including arrests, executions, and acts of terror against civilians

@Groovy and niels nielson, both the answer and the comment would benefit from some references on the quantity and frequency of the killing of collaborators, killing of German officials, of whether there was a Quisling government of collaborators, and both collaborator and German reprisals, and how all compared to the occupation of say France or Poland.  Niels, was a single movie your reference?

No. I got the info from my dad.

*** IMO, not have any impact or have a negative impact on the Danish peoples, and negligible impact on the war?
A good example of a loaded question. Now remove this from a question. :) Why ask a question with some padding inside trying to push the answer into a direction you like?
And answering your question - yes. Because people who work with enemies and for enemies ARE your enemies. And it's totally fine to kill your enemies who came and occupied your country during the war. Regardless of their passport. Moreover treason was always considered even a more serious moral wrongdoing. So actually from this point of view collaborators were morally are the first targets even before Wehrmacht staff.
